# recorrer los input check creados de una base de datos y darle valor cada uno de ellos e insertarlo en la base de dato

Tags: php, mysqli, bucle-for

He creado una tabla de datos llamada productos, la cual recorro en un apartado producto de otro formulario, que quería insertara cada input check su valor correspondiente en una base de datos columna. 
Este es el código de las tabla de producto que he creado:
en el apartado que lo recorro el codigo con el bucle while  lo que pretendo que la pagina sea dinamica con lo cual cada input se genere solo cuando  otro formulario  se rellene esta el el codigo de la tabla  que voy a mandar:

```html
<form action="includes/body/tablasproductos.php" method="POST">
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label>Nombre Comercial</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="serie" name="nombre_comercial">
      <label>Nº Regitro</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationTooltip01" placeholder="Nº Registro" name="numero_registro">
      <label>Mat. Activa y %</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationTooltip01" placeholder="Mat. Activa y %" name="material">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label>Dosis</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationTooltip01" placeholder="Dosis" name="Dosis">
      <label>Cant. Apli.</label> 
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationTooltip01" placeholder="Cant. Apli." name="Cantidad">
      <label>Pl. Seguridad</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationTooltip01" placeholder="Pl. Seguridad" name="plazSeguridad"> </div>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info rounded-pill" name="añadir_productos" placeholder="Añadir" value="Añadir">
 
</form>
```

en la primera tabla que he añadio es la que voy seleccionar en el siguiente codigo y lo recorro con un bucle while para que sea dinamico. Y aqui esta es mi duda y mi dolor de cabeza  cuando clickeo cada input check  quiero que se añada en un campo todo los nombre_comercial en una sola columna es decir si quiero elegir dos o tres  lo inserte  en la base de dato y lo que me pasa el problemas es que solo guarda uno y siempre es el ultimo input seleccionado. esta es mi duda.

```html
<!--MODAL DEL FORMULARIO DE HACER BOLETINES -->
<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg-boletines" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="moda-body ">
                <div class="container-fluid ">
                    <div class="col-12 p-5">
                        <form action="includes/body/trabajos/trboletin.php" method="POST">
                            <div class="form-rows">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Detalle de los locales </label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="ej: R.V o R.F.M" name="locales">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                                    <label>Gerencia Nombre:</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationTooltip01" placeholder="Gerencia" name="gerencia">

                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                                    <label>Estación nombre:</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationTooltip01" placeholder="Estación nombre" name="estacion">

                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                                    <label>Operario/Brigada Nombre</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationTooltip01" pllesaceholder="OPERARIO/BRIGADA" name="operario">

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-row">
                                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="medidas" id="inlineRadio1" value="Vigilacia/ monitorización">
                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">Vigilacia/ monitorización</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="medidas" id="inlineRadio1" value="Medidas de Control Directo">
                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1"> Medidas de Control Directo</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="container-fluid">
                                <h5 class="text-center">Tipo de servicios</h5>
                                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="tratamientos" id="inlineRadio1" value="Tratamientos Físico">
                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1"> Tratamientos Físico</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="tratamientos" id="inlineRadio2" value="Tratamiento Biólogico">
                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio2"> Tratamiento Biólogico</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="tratamientos" id="inlineRadio1" value="Tratamiento Físico-Químico">
                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">Tratamiento Físico-Químico</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="tratamientos" id="inlineRadio2" value="Tratamiento Quimico">
                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio2">Tratamiento Quimico</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!--LAS TRES DDD-->
                            <div class="form-row justify-content-between">
                                <div class="form-check form-check-inline mb-6 mr-sm-2">
                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="inlineFormCheck" name="check[]" value="desratizacion">
                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineFormCheck">
                                        desratización
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-check form-check-inline mb-6 mr-sm-2">
                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="inlineFormCheck" name="check[]" value="desinsectacion">
                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineFormCheck">
                                        Desinsectación
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-check form-check-inline mb-6 mr-sm-2">
                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="inlineFormCheck" name="check[]" value="desinfeccion">
                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineFormCheck">
                                        Desinfección
                                    </label>
                                </div>

                            </div>

                            <div class="form-row">
                                <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">IDENTIFICACIÓN DEL TRATAMIENTO FÍSICO, FÍSICO-QUÍMICO, BIOLÓGICO UTILIZADO, en su caso:</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="identificcion de tratamientos " name="inden_trata">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <h6 class="text-center">Medidas a Adoptar</h6>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Medidas sobre los elementos estructurales y constructivos </label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Medidas" name="Med_elem_estruc">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Medidas de optimización de las condiciones higiénico-sanitarias y ambientales </label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Medidas" name="Med_higienico">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Medidas sobre el desarrolo de comportamientos y hábitos saludables </label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Medidas" name="Med_hab_salud">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Especie Tratadas</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="ciudad" name="especie">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Lugar objeto de control</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="ciudad" name="lugar">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="container">
                                <p>Producto utilizados</p>
                                <?php
                                require ('db.php');


                                $productos = "SELECT nombre_comercial FROM productos";
                                $listaprodutos = mysqli_query($conn, $productos);


                                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($listaprodutos)){
                                    
                                    ?>
                                    <div class="form-check">  
                                       
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="defaultCheck1" name="producto[] value= "<?php echo $row['nombre_comercial'];?>" >
      <!--aqui  recorro la informacion del codigo anterior con el bucle while y cojo los input check lo pongo de nombre producto  -->                  
                                        
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck1">

                                            <?php echo $row['nombre_comercial']; ?>
                                        </label>
                                    </div>


                              <?php } ?>
                                
                              
                                <div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-4">
                                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                        <span class="input-group-text">En </span>
                                    </div>
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="lugar " aria-label="lugardd" class="form-control">
                                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                        <span class="input-group-text">; a </span>
                                    </div>
                                    <input type="text" aria-label="Last name" class="form-control">
                                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                        <span class="input-group-text">de</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <input type="text" aria-label="Last name" class="form-control">
                                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                        <span class="input-group-text">de 201</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <input type="text" aria-label="Last name" class="form-control">

                                </div>

                            </div>


                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info rounded-pill" name="hacer_boletin" placeholder="enviar" value="Añadir">
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

esta es la consulta que quiero generar los productos seleccionado  lo inserto  una consulta sql  pero esta dentro de un bucle for para que inserta este bucle lo busque en una informacion por internet que decia que la variable $i daba su valores de los nombre comercia pero solo me guarda 1 en la base de dato. 
Estoy pensando que mi plantamiento es incorrecto . 
Ante mano agradezco vuestra atencion y dedicadeza en ayudarme . gracias

```html
<?php
include ('../db.php');

if (isset($_POST['hacer_boletin'])) {
    $locales= $_POST['locales'];
    $gerencia =$_POST['gerencia'];
    $estacion= $_POST['estacion'];
    $operario=$_POST['operario'];
    $medidas=$_POST['medidas'];
    $tratamientos=$_POST['tratamientos'];
    //LAS TRES DDD
    $check= $_POST['check'];

    $inden_trata= $_POST['inden_trata'];
   
    $Med_elem_estruc=$_POST[ 'Med_elem_estruc'];
    $Med_higienico=$_POST[ 'Med_higienico'];
    $Med_hab_salud=$_POST[ 'Med_hab_salud'];
    $especie=$_POST['especie'];
    $lugar=$_POST['lugar'];

    //seleccionar productos utilizados
   
    $producto =$_POST['producto'];
    
     $cont = count ($producto);
     
    for($i=0; $i < $cont; $i++){
 $guardar = "INSERT INTO boletines ( locales , gerencia , estacion , operario , vigilancia , tratamientos , desratizacion , desinsectacion , desinfeccion , indentrata , Medelemestruc , Medhigienico, Medhabsalud, especie, lugar, productos) VALUES ( '$locales', '$gerencia', '$estacion', '$operario', '$medidas', '$tratamientos', '$check[0]', '$check[1]' , '$check[2]','$inden_trata', '$Med_elem_estruc', '$Med_higienico', '$Med_hab_salud', '$especie','$lugar',' $producto[$i]' )";

}


$resultado = mysqli_query($conn, $guardar);
     if($resultado){
         echo "esta guadando bien los datos ";
     }else{
         echo "ERROR : ".$guardar."<br>".mysqli_error($conn);
     }
}

?>
```

Comment: ¿Los datos que requieres te llegan desde formulario correctamente? ¿tienes el problema a la hora de guardarlos en base de datos?

Comment: en el bucle for ese es el problemas que tengo , es que solo me guarda solo el ultimo  input seleccionado es decir si creo 3 solo el tercero me lo guarda , que tengo que hacer ??

Comment: ¿Tienes el problema al obtener los valores de los grupos de input radio?

Comment: en <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="defaultCheck1" name="producto[]" value= "<?php echo $row['nombre_comercial'];?>" > tengo que poner  value= "<?php echo $producto['producto']; ?>"

Comment: que tengo que hacer para dar los valores en este caso los imput radio

Answer (score 1):

Parece que tienes errores al imprimir este bloque:

```
// inicio bucle ($rows as $row)
<input class="form-check-input" 
    type="checkbox" 
    id="defaultCheck1" 
    name="producto[] 
    value= "<?php echo $row['nombre_comercial'];?>"

    ...
// fin bucle
```

Corregido:

```
// inicio bucle ($rows as $row)
$cont = 0
<input class="form-check-input" 
    type="checkbox" 
    id="defaultCheck_<?php echo $cont; ?>" 
    name="producto"
    value= "<?php echo $row['nombre_comercial']; ?>">

    $cont++;

    ...
// fin bucle
```

> Editada

Si quieres poder seleccionar varios nombres de producto dentro de un grupo usa *checkboxes*, para seleccionar solo uno usa *radios*.

Comment: for($i=0; $i < $cont; $i++){//mi consulta } lo hago de esta mandera for($cont=0; $i < $cont; $cont++){//mi consulta } cont es una varialbe count de producto

Comment: me sale varios problemas  Notice: Undefined index: producto in C:\xampp\htdocs\trenes\includes\body\trabajos\trboletin.php on line 25

Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in C:\xampp\htdocs\trenes\includes\body\trabajos\trboletin.php on line 27

Comment: no se si estamos en el mismo, sitio... separa la extracción de datos que vas a enviar para crear el formulario, del formulario y del tratamiento de los datos que envía el formulario. Haz debug de la parte uno antes de generar la vista para ver que tienes los datos necesarios. Haz debug de los datos que envie el formulario antes de tratar de almacenarlos.